# Count number of ways to divide a number in 4 parts

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Given a positive integer n, find number of ways to divide n in four parts or represent n as sum of four positive integers. Here n varies from 0 to 5000.

```
def foo(target, k, j):
    count = 0
    map = {} 
    if target in map.keys() and map[target] == k:
        return map[target]
    if target == 0 and k == 0:
        return 1
    if target <= 0 or k < 0:
        return 0
    for i in range(j, target+1):
        count += foo(target-i, k-1, i)
    map[target] = count
    return count

print(foo(10, 4, 1))
```

I have solved this problem with above recursive solution but I just saw someone with below dynamic programming solution.

f(0,0) = 1

f(target, k) = 0 if k > target or (target > 0 and k = 0)

f(target, k) = f(target-k, k) + f(target-1, k-1)

Can someone enlighten me on this solution?

Comment: `f(target, k) = f(target-k, k) + p(target-1, k-1)` what is function `p`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That solution is correct but a little bit tricky, and I will try my best to illustrate it clearly to you.

If `target=25` and we split it into `25=9+7+5+4`. And we express it by 4 columns(1*9, 1*7, 1*5, 1*4):

[image: 25=9+7+5+4]

But in another perspective, you can view the image as 9 rows(1*4, 1*4, 1*4 , 1*4, 1*3, 1*2, 1*2, 1*1, 1*1).

So, you will find your solution is constructing the image by column ways, and that solution is by row ways.

So we come to that solution for details:

- f(target, k) = f(target-k, k) + f(target-1, k-1)
- f(target, k): `target` tiles remain and the length of the row is `k`
- f(target - k, k): put a row of length `k`
- f(target - 1, k - 1): put just one tile to rightest column(ensuring the  answer is positive integer), and decrease the length of the row by 1.

That's all.

If you still got any question, you may leave a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Given a number n, find the number of ways you can represent n as sum of `x1+x2+x3+x4` such that `xi>=0`
The answer will be `(n+3)C(3)`
In general, `x1+x2+x3+...+xn=k with xi>=0` has the solution `(k+n-1)C(n-1)`
Here, k=n and n=4.